# What is : operator in Embedded C

Tags: c, struct, embedded, stm32, bit-fields

In a project of STM32, I came through a code like this :

```
typedef union {
    struct __attribute__ ((packed)){        
        uint8_t ModePin0 :1;                
        uint8_t ModePin1 :1;
        uint8_t ModePin2 :1;
        uint8_t ModePin3 :1;
    } dmxModeBytes;
    uint16_t dmxMode;
} dmxModeUnion;
```

So, my question is what is the meaning of `:1` after `ModePin0` variable and for similar variables?
Is it related to memory alignment?

Comment: This is some seriously sloppy code. Basically it guarantees nothing about the behavior of those struct members, it's non-standard, non-portable goo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an operator it is a declaration of a bit field. The number after the sign ':' specifies the number of bits (the width) in the bit field.

From the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 9 A member of a structure or union may have any complete object type
> other than a variably modified type.123) In addition, a member may be
> declared to consist of a specified number of bits (including a sign
> bit, if any). Such a member is called a bit-field; 124) its width is
> preceded by a colon.

Comment: So, `uint8_t ModePin0 :1` means the `ModePin0` will contain only 1 bit?

Comment: @AhmadYeaseenKhan You are right. It will contain one bit that can store two values: 0 and 1.

Comment: And the four `ModePinx` members are all part of the same `uint8_t`, so they cover the lower four bits of the struct (and the union).

Comment: Just remember that the _position_ and _order_ of the bit fields is _**implementation defined**_. Make sure you and your compiler agree on that. Never assume that bit N will match some bitfield’s N.